# Python: Issue with difference between webdriver Firefox and PhantomJS

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've been working on this Python script for the past day or two and all is working fine when I use the Firefox webdriver, but when I switch to use a headless browser like PhantomJS it fails on the line with `setNumber = parseSetNumber(setName[0])` with the error `Error: list index out of range` due to `setName` being empty.

The line before it `setName = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a/text()")` returns nothing when using the PhantomJS webdriver only, if using the Firefox webdriver it returns a value fine.

The error only happens when I switch the webdriver from Firefox to PhantomJS. I use PhantomJS as the script is run on a linux server.

```
import time
import os.path
import lxml.html as LH
import re
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from random import randint
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PARAMS = sys.argv
URL = PARAMS[1]
BASEURL = URL[:URL.rfind('/')+1]

# Parses the set name for the set number
def parseSetNumber(string):
    string = string.split(' ')
    stringLength = len(string)
    string = string[(stringLength - 1)]
    if string.replace('.','').isdigit():
        return string
    else:
        return ""

# Returns set reference for this site
def parseRefId(string):
    string = string.split('_')
    return str(string[2])

try:
    PAGE_NUMBER = 1

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get initial page

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(PARAMS[1])

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get page count

    # Give page time to load
    time.sleep(2)

    PAGE_RAW = driver.page_source
    PAGE_RAW = LH.fromstring(PAGE_RAW)
    PAGE_COUNT_RAW = PAGE_RAW.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pageControlMenu')]/div/ul/li")
    PAGE_COUNT = len(PAGE_COUNT_RAW) - 2

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Get page if its not page one

    while PAGE_NUMBER <= PAGE_COUNT:
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Create empty file
        FILE_NAME = PARAMS[3] + 'json/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H") + '_' + str(PARAMS[2]) + '_' + str(PAGE_NUMBER) + '.json'
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Create JSON file if it doesnt exist
        if os.path.exists(FILE_NAME)==False:
            JSON_FILE = open(FILE_NAME, "a+", encoding="utf-8")
        else:
            JSON_FILE = open(FILE_NAME, "w", encoding="utf-8")
        JSON_FILE.write("{")
        #--------------------------------------------------
        # Click page for next page if not page 1
        if PAGE_NUMBER > 1:
            index = 0
            for atag in PAGE_COUNT_RAW:
                if index == PAGE_NUMBER:
                    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pageControlMenu')]/div/ul/li")
                    if elements:
                        element = elements[index].find_elements_by_xpath("./a")
                        if element:
                            element[0].click()
                            time.sleep(randint(3,5))
                index += 1
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Remove survey box if it pops up and log
        try:
            surveyBox = driver.find_element_by_link_text("No, thanks")
            if surveyBox:
                surveyBox.click()
                print("Store[" + str(PARAMS[2]) + "]: Survey box found on page - " + str(PAGE_NUMBER))
        except:
            print("Store[" + str(PARAMS[2]) + "]: No survey box on page - " + str(PAGE_NUMBER))
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Proces page
        # If page is greater then 1 then get the page source of the new page.
        if PAGE_NUMBER > 1:
            PAGE_RAW = driver.page_source
            PAGE_RAW = LH.fromstring(PAGE_RAW)
        PAGE_RAW = PAGE_RAW.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'estore_product_container')]")
        index = 0
        size = len(PAGE_RAW)
        for atag in PAGE_RAW:
            if PAGE_NUMBER > 1 and index == 0:
                WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a")))
            setStore = PARAMS[2]
            setName = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a/text()")
            setNumber = parseSetNumber(setName[0])
            setPrice = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_price')]/text()")
            setLink = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a/@href")
            setRef = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_price')]/@id")
            if setRef:
                setRef = parseRefId(setRef[0])
            if re.search('[0-9\.]+', setPrice[0]) is not None:
                JSON_FILE.write("\"" + str(index) + "\":{\"store\":\"" + str(setStore) + "\",\"name\":\"" + str(setName[0]) + "\",\"number\":\"" + str(setNumber) + "\",\"price\":\"" + re.search('[0-9\.]+', setPrice[0]).group() + "\",\"ref\":\"" + str(setRef) + "\",\"link\":\"" + str(setLink[0]) + "\"}")
                if index+1 < size:
                    JSON_FILE.write(",")
            index += 1
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Close JSON file
        JSON_FILE.write("}")
        JSON_FILE.close()
        #--------------------------------------------------
        ## Increment page number
        PAGE_NUMBER += 1
        #--------------------------------------------------

    #--------------------------------------------------
    ## Close webdriver
    driver.quit()
    #--------------------------------------------------

except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ' + str(e.args[0]))

# Remove gecodriver.log file
GHOSTDRIVER_FILE = str(PARAMS[3]) + 'jobs/ghostdriver.log'
if os.path.exists(GHOSTDRIVER_FILE)==True:
    os.remove(GHOSTDRIVER_FILE)
```

**Update**

It looks like these are the only two lines not working with PhantomJS, they both return an empty value.

```
setName = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a/text()")
setLink = atag.xpath("./div[contains(@class, 'product_info')]/div[contains(@class, 'product_name')]/a/@href")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I've solved this issue, I had to add the `set_windows_size` option for the webdriver when using PhantomJS.

Originally:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(PARAMS[1])
```

Solution:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get(PARAMS[1])
```

Now the PhantomJS webdriver works as is expected in the same way the Firefox webdriver works.